# Gif in splash in xml

Tags: android, android-layout

I need a help about to load gif file in splash.

Want disc should be rotate below logo.

Help me to fit the gif in splash.

Comment: always use png file...

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic, because it lacks sufficient information.

Comment: you can follow my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can follow this example

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private ImageView splashImageView;
    boolean splashloading = false;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        splashImageView = new ImageView(this);
        splashImageView.setScaleType(ScaleType.FIT_XY);
        splashImageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
        setContentView(splashImageView);
        // interesting music
        /**
         * Gets your sound file from res/raw
         */
        splashloading = true;
        Handler h = new Handler();
        h.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                splashloading = false;
                setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            }

        }, 3000);

    }
```

Comment: It is splash screen example